# PHP custom regex in url

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-match

I am new in Stackoverflow and I have a simple question: I need to create a regex to match a custom patterns in string. I want to create a regex to detect this url:

```
/post-title-92581_1.html

where $match[0] = 92581 and $match[1] = 1
```

I created this regex `((\-[0-9]+)_([1-2]{1}).html)` works fine,but this returns:

```
$match[0] // -92581
$match[1] // 1
```

if i change string to `/post-title-925-81_1.html` i get

```
$match[0] // -81
$match[1] // 1
```

I only want to get the **FIRST MATCH** `(-925)` without "`-`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the - outside of the brackets...

```
-([0-9]+)_([1-2]{1}).html
```

Everything inside the brackets gets returned as a match!

Comment: This working worderful, exactly that I needed,thanks.

Comment: This gives you 81 on the second case though, while I thought you wanted 925.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to split the RegEx:

A first regex that searches for "925" (**-(\d+)[-_]**),

A second regex that searches for the last part (**_([1-2]{1}).html$**).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate it,now I understand better Regular Expressions,it worked for me,thanks!.